# Highlight Plotly heatmap cell or change the color of a specific heatmap cell in Plotly

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Is it possible to highlight or change the color of a specific heatmap cell in Plotly, I have a requirement of accepting the user input and then highlight those cells on the heatmap. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks